# Limit the select query batch size

Tags: mongodb, hadoop

I am using `MongoTool` runner to import the data from mongoDB to Hadoop mapreduce jobs. Due to the size of the data i am getting `OutOfMemoryError`. So i want to limit the number of records i fetch in a batch fashion.

```
MongoConfigUtil.setQuery()
```

can set only the query but i cannot set the size to limit the number of records fetched. What i am looking for is something like

MongoConfigUtil.setBatchSize()
and then
MongoConfigUtil.getNextBatch()

something like that.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: There is something called mongoconfigutil.setsplitsize(conf,value) which will be helpful in limiting the input split size.

Comment: So if i set that should i worry about getting the next batch of records or the API itself automatically will takecare of it?

Comment: API should take care of it...

Comment: I still face the same error i have set the splitSize to 64 MB. Do you have a complete sample for reading and writing into mongodb from hadoop. I find some examples in github but they are too big to understand. I just want a simple read and write from and to mongodb from hadoop mapreduce jobs. kindly let me know how i can get ride of this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the *setLimit* method of the class MongoInputSplit, passing the number of document that you want to fetch.

```
myMongoInputSplitObj = new MongoInputSplit(*param*)
myMongoInputSplitObj.setLimit(100)
```

[MongoConfigUtil setLimit](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/HADOOP-267)

[Allow users to set the limit on MongoInputSplits (HADOOP-267).](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/commit/3f3b09cc73134cab74663009420447df05634dce)